# How to turn off my ubuntu web camera?

Tags: 16.04, hp, webcam, camera

I was using facebook messenger, and When I finished my call, the web cam stilled working.I have an integrated camera in my laptop HP 630.
Is there a way to turn it off ? Thanks.

Comment: It might just be glitched. Have you tried restarting?

Comment: @NeoTheThird shameless plug, but this most probably readily available and thus cheaper: http://askubuntu.com/a/779909/75166

Comment: the problem is solved, but I am using it :xD

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you guys, the problem is gone.
- I used the command : **lsof | grep video0** to find the software using my webcam. It was *FireFox*.
- I just restarted *FireFox*, and then the webcam turned off.

Comment: Just run `lsof /dev/video0`. That's often much faster than running lsof on all files

Answer (score 10):

If the webcam behaves weirdly, not automatically turning off for example, you can:

To **disable** the webcam run:

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
```

It removes the module from the Linux Kernel.

To **re-enable** the webcam you can either restart or run:

```
sudo modprobe -a uvcvideo
```

Reinserts the module.

Answer (score 3):

1. `sudo rmmod -f uvcvideo`(to kill laptop camera)
2. `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo`(to restart the video module)
3. `sudo modprobe uvcvideo`(to restart the laptop camera)
4. `sudo modprobe -a uvcvideo`(can be used while skipping steps 2&3 to
   restart the camera directly)

Comment: lsmod | grep uvcvideo (to check if camera killed or alive)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the application name, you can use the following to get the process ID:

```
ps -fA | grep application_name
Output: process_name PID PPID .....
```

Then you can kill the process using:

```
kill -9 PID
```