# Indicator to enable / disable Webcam

Tags: indicator, webcam, gnome-shell

I recently bought a Webcam to be used for making Youtube videos, and connected it to my Ubuntu Bionic PC.

I'd like to have an indicator to disable the Webcam when it is not in use, similar to the Touchpad Indicator (for laptops).

The Webcam has a light that comes on when it's in use, but I would feel 
safer if I had a "switch".

I couldn't find anything in the Setting and I also tried to search for "cam" in the Gnome Extensions Web site, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First verify the commands [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/896776/67335) work, or you can find equivalent terminal commands.

Then install [indicator-script-runner](https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335) and add those commands in.  You might/could alter the `sudo` to be `echo password | sudo -S` where password is your actual password; all depends on how secure/accessible your computer.