# ubuntu webcam light stays on after call skype ends

Tags: skype, webcam

I have a problem with skype on ubuntu. After each call ends, the light on the webcam stays on.
Verison I have are as follows:
ubuntu 19.04
skype 8.58.0.93
webcam logitech c170

Comment: If you quit skype does it go away?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/a/897409/307670

Comment: @Robby1212, yep, when I quit, the light turns off.

Comment: @Graham, no it doesn't. I don't want to "turn the light off" manually after each Skype call. I think it's supposed to turn itself off automatically.

Comment: Is Skype the latest version? Have you checked their bug logs to see if it's already been noted?

Comment: @Robby1212, current Sype version for linux is 8.85.0.93, which is the one I have. Did not go though bug logs, but "googled" it everywhere, did not find anything related to fixing the bug once and for all, without any scripts or manual turn offs.